# Azure Data Explorer get Distinct values and order by

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, distinct-values

I'm facing some troubles to get the distinct values from a JSON and sort them alphabetical.
The JSON in stored in a Dynamic type, column is named `data`.

The JSON:

```
"Data": [
    {
        "Code": "CC",
    },
    {
        "Code": "AA",
    },
    {
        "Code": "BB",
    }
]
```

I tried following things:

```
    Table
    | mv-expand data
    | distinct tostring(data.Code)
//get the distincts


    Table
    | mv-expand data
    | extend Codes= tostring(data.Code)
    | distinct tostring(data.Code)
    | sort by Codes asc
//Try to sort
```

I expect the output like this:

```
AA
BB
CC
```

I'm able to get all the distinct codes, but the sorting is not working or applied.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help:

```
print data = dynamic([ { "Code" : "CC" }, { "Code" : "AA" }, { "Code" : "BB" }])
| mv-expand data
| extend Codes= tostring(data.Code)
| distinct Codes
| sort by Codes asc
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
let ser_num =
InsightsMetrics 
| distinct substring(Computer,10,2);

ser_num 
| order by Column1 asc
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?